# Auto convert HEIF to JPEG on direct upload with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, heif

If user uploads HEIF file, I would like to convert it to JPEG in Rails 6 application on Active Storage. This would be a system vide function. JPEG image cannot be a variant, because photo needs to be analyzed (I need the EXIF data from it).

Should the conversion be triggered during the analysis of the original file, or is it more appropriate place for this without slowing down the upload itself.